# Can't get product detail data (NEXTJS 14)

Tags: next.js

I am currently making an e-commerce website. My project uses NextJS. Currently I'm working on a **product detail page**. I want to get a product** based on the product's slug**. For example: **http://localhost:3000/product/armchair-royal-shoulder-mb-ld-17**. The slug here is: armchair-royal-shoulder-mb-ld-17. But **I got an error**: **data: {success: false, message: 'Something went wrong! Please try again later'}**. Please help me see where I am going wrong. This is my code. **I got the params  ~ ProductDetailsPage ~ params: {productSlug: 'armchair-royal-shoulder-mb-ld-17'}** but can not get the data. Please help me take a look!
**api/product/[productSlug]/route.js
**

```js
import { connect } from "@/backend/config/mongodb";
import Product from "@/backend/models/Product";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

connect()

export async function GET(req, res) {
  try {
    const { productSlug } = req.params;
    const product = await Product.findOne({ slug: productSlug });

    if (product) {
      return NextResponse.json({
        success: true,
        data: product,
      });
    } else {
      return NextResponse.json({
        success: false,
        message: 'Product not found',
      });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return NextResponse.json({
      success: false,
      message: 'Something went wrong! Please try again later',
    });
  }
}
```

**app/product/[productSlug]/page.jsx**

```js
'use client'
import ProductDetail from "@/app/components/product/ProductDetail"
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react"

const ProductDetailsPage = ({ params }) => {
    console.log(' ~ ProductDetailsPage ~ params:', params)

    const [product, setProduct] = useState(null);

    const getProductDetails = async () => {
        try {
            const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/product/${params.productSlug}`,
                {
                    method: 'GET'
                }
            )
            console.log(' ~ getProductDetails ~ res:', res)
            const data = await res.json()
            console.log('data: ', data)
            setProduct(data)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("[productId_GET]", error);
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getProductDetails();
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            <ProductDetail product={product} />
        </div>
    )

}

export default ProductDetailsPage
```

I want to find the error in code above. I use MongoDB to store data

this is my log

```json
data:  {success: false, message: 'Something went wrong! Please try again later'}
```

~ ProductDetailsPage ~ params: {productSlug: 'sofa-maxine-m2-3c-da-mush-1141-vact8377'}

Comment: If you open the product URL (.e.g: `http://localhost:3000/product/armchair-royal-shoulder-mb-ld-17`) directly on a browser can you get the expected response?

Comment: When I open the product URL, it will appear the product detail page, BUT there is no data in there and in Console tab it show Object
message
: 
"Something went wrong! Please try again later"
success
: 
false
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object

Comment: Please check if you are able to connect to mongodb. Seperately check for the connection to the database. There may be problem and what is log of this  { catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return NextResponse.json({
      success: false,
      message: 'Something went wrong! Please try again later',
    }); } 
What is log of this line in above code console.error(error)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with getting params. In a `route.ts` file defined inside an dynamic route such as `[productSlug]` folder, you need to get the params using context instead of request.

Modify the `api/product/[productSlug]/route.js` file as below

```
import { connect } from "@/backend/config/mongodb";
import Product from "@/backend/models/Product";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function GET(req, context) {
  try {
    await connect();
    const { productSlug } = context.params;
    const product = await Product.findOne({ slug: productSlug });

    if (product) {
      return NextResponse.json({
        success: true,
        data: product,
      });
    } else {
      return NextResponse.json({
        success: false,
        message: "Product not found",
      });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return NextResponse.json({
      success: false,
      message: "Something went wrong! Please try again later",
    });
  }
}
```

You can find more about the `context` [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route#context-optional)